# TypeError: The comparison function must be either a function or undefined

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Write a function named "sort_by_average" that takes a list/array of key-value stores as a parameter where each key-value store has keys "ratings", "budget", and "box_office" where budget and box_office are integers and ratings is a list of integers. Sort the input based on the average of the values in "ratings"

```
function sort_by_average(lista){
    for(var i of lista){
        lista.sort(i.ratings.reduce/i.ratings.length);
    }
    return lista;
}
```

I am getting TypeError: The comparison function must be either a function or undefined. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hello mate, the [Array.protoytype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) requires a `function` as parameter or `undefined`, that's why you encounter `TypeError`.
You also don't have to loop through the list to sort it, you can take a look at the example provided in the link above.

Answer (score 2):

> If compareFunction is supplied, all non-undefined array elements are
>   sorted according to the return value of the compare function (all
>   undefined elements are sorted to the end of the array, with no call to
>   compareFunction).

So you have to create a function like this and pass it to sort():

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)